# Which units does Foreign Princess affect?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

Foreign Princess says:

> Foreign Army units within two spaces take -2/+2 to damage dealt/taken.

"Foreign" to whom? Is Azura counted as Nohrian, Hoshidan or a Vallite? What if Kata, Rhajat or Nina inherits this skill? Does this apply only to battles in my castle?

There are a lot of opinions about this online, so I'm wondering if anyone has tested it.

Comment: I'm guessing she counts as whatever type Corrin is.  I have nothing to back that up, however.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fire Emblem wikia page on Foreign Princess](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Foreign_Princess):

> All **enemy** ("Foreign Army") units within a 2 tile radius of the user deal 2 less damage to allied units and receive 2 additional damage from allied units. It is learned by Songstresses at lvl 35.

Thus, it looks like "foreign army" just means "not your army".